# Angular 2 & .Net Web Api 2.0 resource does not support method PUT

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, cors, angular2-routing

I have an angular 2/4 application which makes request to a .Net Web Api 2.0 using Windows authentication. I can make GET and DELETE requests that work perfectly. However when I try to do POST or PUT request I am getting the following error:

**PUT**

> The requested resource does not support http method 'PUT

**POST**

> The request entity's media type 'text/plain' is not supported for this resource. No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type from content with media type 'text/plain

I know windows authenticaion is working because I can make GET and DELETE Reqeusts. I have the Content-Type header set to application/json and I have handled cors and preflight with the following in my Application_BeginRequest method

```
var referrer = Request.UrlReferrer.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
if (Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Remove("Access-Control-Allow-Origin");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", referrer);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 200;
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}

if (Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Origin"))
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Remove("Access-Control-Allow-Origin");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", referrer);
}
```

I have also included the following in my web.config

**Cors**

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, HEAD, OPTIONS" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, X-Pagination, Authorization" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Expose-Headers" value="X-Pagination" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

**Windows Authentication**

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

Any idea what could cause GET and DELETE to work but not POST, PUT, PATCH?

**Update - Controller Methods**

```
[Route("")]
[HttpPut]
public IHttpActionResult Put([FromBody] Header updatedEntity)
{
    if (updatedEntity == null)
        return BadRequest();

    var entity = UnitOfWork.Headers.Get(updatedEntity.Id);
    if (entity == null)
        return NotFound();

    // Setup up entity

    UnitOfWork.Commit();

    return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("", Name = "RouteName")]
public IHttpActionResult List([FromUri] HeaderResourceParameters parameters)
{
    parameters = parameters ?? new HeaderResourceParameters();

    var recipients = UnitOfWork.Recipients.GetAll().ToList();

    var entities = UnitOfWork.Headers.List(parameters)
        .Select(o => new HeaderViewModel
        {
            // Entity Setup
        });

    if (entities == null)
        return NotFound();

    return Ok(entities);
}
```

Comment: can you add <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" /> on config httpProtocol->customHeaders

Comment: @brykneval I can't have start fields when using windows authentication. I also handle that in the Application_BeginRequest Mtehod

Comment: How you are testing it? also can you please provide your controller code here?

Comment: Have you decorated your method with `[AcceptVerbs("PUT")]`? Undecorated methods are working by Naming Convetion

Comment: Also see: https://blog.appliedis.com/2013/03/25/web-api-mixing-traditional-verb-based-routing/

Comment: @BhadhriVishalKannan I am testing in with Angular 4 since postman and Fiddler don't support windows authentication to my knowledge.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt I tried [AcceptVerbs("PUT")] and it doesn't work I am using attribute routing with [HttpPost] & [HttpPost] (See above post of controller methods).